Opening a new tab using the google search bar w/o closing current website searched
When you're using the google search bar once you are on a website I am unable to open a new tab without the current one closing. If you use chrome you can always open a new tab but does Chrome have a search bar widget for the home screen?

Chrome has two widgets for searches:

Chrome search and
Chrome shortcuts which has a search bar among other shortcuts

The first image shows where you can find them. Depending on your launcher, you can long press on the Chrome icon, then select widget. Or you can long press on an empty space, this should show either to go the launcher's settings or the widgets'page.
The second image shows them on the home screen.


